# Finding the letters in a string of characters

Tags: string-manipulation

So I have some strings of characters which size are not constant.

Example: Mystring may appear like "12,!abcdefghaijk,.54" and I want to extract only the letters "abcdefghaijk".

I tried two approaches (se below). I think it would be logic to first get the size of the string!?

While trying to extract the letters, I found a difference in the results:

```mathematica
Mystring = {"123456789"}

n = StringLength[Mystring]
(* ans: {9} *)

Newstring = StringTake[Mystring,{2,9}]
(* answer: {23456789} - "OK" *)

Newstring = StringTake[Mystring,{2,n}]
(* {{12,9}} - "Wrong" *)
```

Thank you very much in advance for any comments that you may have.

Comment: The discrepancy between the two is because `n` is not simply the number `9` but the list `{9}`. So define `n` as follows instead: `n=First[StringLength[Mystring]]`. Not sure if that answers your question? I find the latter part of your post to be difficult to understand.

Comment: You are fooling yourself.  "n" is not an integer, but a list: {9}. THat means you are taking the first 2 and the 9th character.

Comment: If `str2 = "12,!abcdefghaijk,.54"` then try: `StringCases[str2, LetterCharacter ..]` or else edit your post further. Thanks.

Comment: I think OP is trying to do `StringTake[Mystring,{2,-1}]`.

Comment: I understand now that n is not simply a number as I defined it. The solution given by Syed solves this one and several of my problems with strings. Thank you all, my question was not clear, thank you for your patience.

Comment: How does one fetch all the characters between say position 3 and "position 5 from the end" of a string"? (Should I write this in a new question?) Thank you.

Comment: This would be a different question, but please don't post it as a new question. This functionality is clearly documented for StringTake.

Answer (score 2):

You introduce some confusion by setting Mystring to be a list

```
Mystring = {"123456789"}
```

Since List is such an important structure in Mathematica, many functions are designed to work naturally with List. Let's demonstrate this by changing Mystring a bit.

```
Mystring = {"123456789","abcde"}
```

Now try

```
StringLength[Mystring]
{* {9, 5} *}
```

See how StringLength automatically looks "inside" of any list? StringTake does the same

```
StringTake[Mystring, {2, 9}]
(* {"23456789", StringTake["abcde", {2, 9}]} *)
```

This time you see error messages, because "abcde" is too short to take 2 through 9 characters. When you tried

```
StringTake[Mystring, {2, n}]
```

the result was unexpected because n was a list, not an integer, and nested lists trigger a different meaning for StringTake. But let's not get into that right now.

So, let's try to answer your request

> I wish Newstring will contain all the characters in Mystring

After a few readings of this, I think what you actually mean is

> I wish Newstring will contain all the **letters** in Mystring

There is built in functionality for this kind of thing, but we need to clean up Mystring first.

```
Mystring = "12,!abcdefghaijk,.54"
```

It's now just a string, instead of a list, and I'm using the more complicated test case. We can get the answer directly:

```
Newstring = StringDelete[Mystring, Except[LetterCharacter]]
```

LetterCharacter is a built-in pattern that can be used for matching in strings. Except is for patterns what Not is for booleans.

Now, if you do have a list

```
stringList = {"12,!abcdefghaijk,.54", "1a2s3d4f5g"}
```

The typical way to apply a function to every element of a list is to Map:

```
StringDelete[Except[LetterCharacter]] /@ stringList
(* {"abcdefghaijk", "asdfg"} *)
```

But StringDelete is one of those functions that is designed to work directly with lists, so you can do this:

```
StringDelete[stringList, Except[LetterCharacter]]
(* {"abcdefghaijk", "asdfg"} *)
```

Comment: lericr: Thank you ever so much, this was really very helpful.